# Cannot install scrapy

Tags: python, windows, pip, scrapy

I am trying to install the scrapy framework and have run into issues already before even installing it. I just installed C++ from Visual Build tools, installed python on my machine, and pip is installed as well. I created a directory, named it scrapy, and finally created a virtual environment called venv. After activating the venv, I type in the command `pip install scrapy` but it returns this long winded message but it is basically:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\my name\source\scrapy\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\my name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e0w0tqi9\\twisted_1f5b116ca84846ad9daa44466c4a8394\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\my name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e0w0tqi9\\twisted_1f5b116ca84846ad9daa44466c4a8394\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\my name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-u2th9gq5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\my name\source\scrapy\venv\include\site\python3.9\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Has anyone ever dealt with this before? All the articles mention uninstalling and reinstalling build tools and I've done that already. Is there something else I am missing? I have also run Visual Studio Code as administrator and still nothing. Been using this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALizgnSFTwQ&t=181s&ab_channel=TraversyMedia) as a guide for installation but it diverges from the get go. I am fairly new to Python frameworks so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: you shouldn't name folders the same as python modules. It messes with imports if those folders become python packages

Comment: @hotgatorade -From the information, we can see that the problem occurs in the installation of the dependency package "twisted", you could refer to this [link](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2881#issuecomment-412333206) to manually install "twisted" or use conda to install it as people said.